# What is the substitue for <Iframe></Iframe> in mobile website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, iframe

I have a question to be asked .

. I have a form in the desktop version of my website this form is an Iframe . Now I am working on the mobile website using JQM framework. I have been told to use some other method to make this form .

. So I want to know what should I use instead of Iframe to develop this form just a general suggestion

Thanks & Regards

Comment: This depends on why you are using an `iframe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A perfectly ordinary link that uses the full (tiny) view port for the resource you want to show.